# Configure in Maven that Eclipse follows maven-surefire-plugin configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit

We got following situation: We have unit and integration tests. Unit test classes end with `Test` and integration tests end with `ITest`. To execute only unit tests at Maven build we use following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*ITest.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

That's working in Maven build, but when I'm executing tests in Eclipse IDE via context menu > *Run as* > *JUnit test* it ignores these excludes and tests with `ITest` at the end fail.

Is there a way to configure (in POM) that Eclipse follows maven-surefire-plugin configuration?

Comment: `Run as > JUnit test` ignores the whole pom. Eclipse has ist own configuration

Comment: Why don't you follow the default naming schema which are already defined in Maven. Unit Test: `*Test.java`Integration Tests: `IT.java*`?

Comment: @khmarbaise That's my favoured solution of course, but it's not my decision, it's a company policy :/

Answer (score 1):

*Run as > JUnit test* does **not** know about your `pom.xml`.

But if you place your unit tests and integration tests in different directories (the [Maven convention](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) suggests `src/test/java` and `src/it/java`), then you can use Eclipse’s ability to run **all** tests in a package or source folder; simply click on the integration-test source folder and select *Run as > JUnit test* from its context menu.

Comment: That's a nice solution, but it's a lot of tests and not all of them are under my control. That's why I need a way via configuration